# "Name" array after a string c#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I've started an old project again (with new ideas and in Unity) and I'm stuck. 
Basically I need a lot of public arrays (mostly so they appear in the editor). Is there a way to "name" those arrays using existing strings?
For example :

```
string[] arrayNames = new string[]{"FirstArray", "SecondArray", "ThirdArray"};
for (int i=0; i<arrowNames.Length; i++){
    //Here i would create the new array using the string
    public Sprite[] arrowNames[i] = new Sprite[10];
    //Code to populate new array comes here
}
```

This code is just the idea of what i need. Anyone know a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you something like `Dictionary<string, Sprite[]>` ?

Comment: @user3185569 Put that as an answer

Comment: Why? It has been asked a million times, just close as duplicate. @Programmer

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok. Didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks @user3185569. As for the duplicate issue, I'm sorry. I looked before but couldn't find.